# jquery polling solution

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, delayed-job, polling

UPDATED:

I'm trying to get jquery smart poll to work for me.  It works fine if the process is ready in the first 2 seconds but if not, it does not retry as it's supposed to.  I'd also like to make the retries time out after a certain number.

https://github.com/hmert/jquery-smart-poll

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $("#load_availables").toggle()
    $.poll(2000,function(retry){
        $.getScript('update_availables.js?job_id=<%= @bed.job_id %>&space_id=<%= @space.id %>', function(response, status){
            if (status == 'success')
                $("#load_availables").toggle()  //works fine if ready
            else
                retry()  //does not retry at all
         })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var retryCount = 0;

$.poll(10000, function(retry){
     retryCount++;
     $.get('something', function(response, status){
       if (status == 'success')
         // Do something
       else
       {
         if(retryCount < 11) retry();
         else return;
       }
     })
   })
```

I haven't had the chance to test this - but, in theory this should do the job.

By the way, as a side note - for the thing you're doing if you'd like to speed up efficiency of your JavaScript, use a comet server and use slow polling. Take a look at http://www.ape-project.org/

Comment: thanks, that will probably work, but I just noticed that retry, either in your example or even the sample code isn't working.  Its returning a 404, so it doesn't do anything from the success, but it's not retrying as it should.

Comment: Is there a retry function in your code? Im not 100% sure which external plugin library you're using.

Comment: using the jquery smart poll https://github.com/jeremyw/jquery-smart-poll/blob/master/lib/jquery.smart-poll.js

Comment: the response is null and i'm sending a status of 404, format.js { render :nothing => true, :status => 404 } which should trigger the retry but doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the jquery plugin Smartupdater

http://www.eslinstructor.net/smartupdater3/

It has all features you need.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never! According the the jQuery docs the get() ajax function fails silently. You will have to handle the .ajaxError() event. http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/